# Partial Intersection between an array and a string with substrings

Tags: javascript, arrays, intersection, partial

I'm trying to push in a second array, the intersection between an array and a string . For example:

```
var animals=["Dog  -   5 years", "Cat    -   10 years"];

var selected=document.getElementById("selectanimals").innerHTML; //which is a string like: "Dog" or "Cat"
```

Is there a way to intersect these two things, by selecting "Dog" or "Cat" in `$selected`, and get just the number of years?

Comment: `selected.map(animal => animals.find(i => i.indexOf(animal) > -1).replace(animal, ''));`? https://jsfiddle.net/judya01o/ . That's a weird design though, you will need to trim whitespaces and remove extra characters, is the `animals` array generated by your code? If so, you should definitely change that.

Comment: `innerHTML` will never return an array. It will only return a string. It might return the string `"Dog, Cat"` but that's just a string that happens to have a comma in it. Putting it in brackets just gives you an array with a single string. You'll need to `split` it to get an array.

Comment: I got the variable animals from php, which get data from database. I got the array with {!! json_encode(array_values($animalsyears) !}} , so @briosheje yes it is generated by PHP because i want to get the number of years.

Comment: If you are the owner of the PHP code, you should just change it to a key -> value pair array instead.

Comment: @HereticMonkey oh okay. So i have to split it and get the array, and then do the intersection.

Comment: @briosheje how can I do it?  I'm using Laravel here and trying to create a new array from javascript only by comparing these arrays. Thank you

Comment: You need to build, in php, an array whose keys are the animals and whose values are the years. I'm not a laravel expert, you should add laravel to the tags and add the relevant PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

i've resolved the problem by my own, but i want to thank you anyway for the tips.
As @HereticMonkey said, any `document.getElementById` returns a string.
So I had the idea to convert the array animals into a string and do the following  operations.

```
var x=animals.toString();
var n=x.indexOf(selected);
if(j){
var g=n-NUMBEROFSPACES
var h=n-ENDOFTHEWORD
var res=x.substring(g,h);
}
alert(res);
```

Actually the code is very simple, but I didn't  think about this solution. It works very well, I hope this one day can help somebody.